# JQuery .click() does not work in new sortable item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have JQuery UI Sortable+Draggable lists, and i use JQuery .click() for all sortable items, but if i drop new item from draggable list to sortable list, this item do not trigger .click() event.

```
$(#sortable li).click(function(){
    alert('Sortable item clicked');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1so55b0t/2/

Why?

---

Okay, i'm replace .click() to .on('click')

And my elements have close button with class .remove and again this does not work for new elements:

```
$('#sortable li').on('click','.remove',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1so55b0t/4/
Why?

Comment: Your jsfiddle sample seems to work.. Are you sure that you enclosed your #sortable li as a string? $("#sortable li")

Comment: Oh GOD... this question have been asked trillion times here on SO, why dont you search a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : As you are moving the `li`s within DOM, it will not applied to previously bind click event handler. Better use click event delegation, which is useful for dynamic / new elements like below

```
$('#sortable').on('click', 'li', function(){
    alert('Sortable item clicked');
});
```

**EDIT** - Use below code to add click handler for remove buttons -

```
$('#sortable').on('click','li .remove',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1so55b0t/6/)**

Comment: this work, but this not work:
    $('#sortable li').on('click', '.remove', function(){
       $(this).parent().remove();
    });

Comment: what is `.remove` button, can you pls post jsfiddle with close button

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1so55b0t/4/

Comment: please check my edit in the answer, - https://jsfiddle.net/1so55b0t/5/

Comment: thanks this work, but how i can click del button(remove), without trigger element click?

Comment: You can use ` e.stopPropagation();`, see this https://jsfiddle.net/1so55b0t/6/

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to append `click` handler to the newly added elements too. Change you code to as below. Check demo - https://jsfiddle.net/1so55b0t/3/.

```
$('#sortable').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert('Sortable item Clicked!');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use this code

```js
 $(document).on('click', '#sortable li', function () {
 
     alert('Sortable item Clicked!');
     });
```

Comment: explain it please